# Is there a way to use jQuery?

Tags: javascript, 10

I heard Drupal 10 will no longer support jQuery out-of-the-box.

Is there a way to use jQuery in Drupal 10?

My guess would be that adding jQuery to a module's composer.json file would allow jQuery code to continue to function. I know this is not best practice, but large sites might need additional time to transition away from jQuery.

Comment: I think jQuery UI is gone in Drupal 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery is still included [in Drupal 10.1core](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.1.x/core/core.libraries.yml#L755).**

If it would be removed in the future you would actually add a libraries file: https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-module-via-librariesyml

I would fully expect a contributor would share such a module.

Comment: I did a search for jQuery for Drupal 10 but did not find any modules yet. Do you know of any?

Comment: It wasn’t removed https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.1.x/core/core.libraries.yml#L755